# SQL Join filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures, left-join

I want to get single row after join as result, where table A can have columns like ID,Name,Age,Surname e.t.c and table B have ID,address e.t.c a person can have multiple addresses and if i use where condition get person from address i am getting multiple rows for the same person which want as single for single person i don't need all the addresses in my result.

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
where b.address=add1 or/and b.address=add2
```

This results same person in different rows with multiple address which causing me redundant data. Can someone please suggest a better way here...!

Comment: Use a Window function to number the ROWS Based on Persons then Select only the Rows that have 1 as Value.

Comment: You need to be more clear with your question. Are you sure you need to join tables over the key `A.ID = B.ID` , what is relation in table `B` addresses , shouldn't you have table `A_ID` key inside. And yes if you have in column `B` three addresses the same person will popup three times. To get only first address you can use `TOP 1`

Comment: You are missing debugging details in your post, like tables definition, data, current output and expected output. Make sure to update your post accordingly.

Comment: you can use an `outer apply` in stead of a join, that would allow you to retrieve only one row

Comment: But without sample data and expected outcome, we can only guess what your real question is, so it's not possible to provide you with an exact answer now

Comment: @AnelHodžić using top 1 results single row but i am missing other person data if both have same addresses i.e. person a with address add1 and add2 is shown but person b with same add1 and add2 is not shown ...i need both but not 4 rows with 2 rows for each person but single row for each persons

Answer (score 1):

By Window Function you can achieve it,

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.PersonId ORDER BY P.PersonId) AS RowNum
FROM Persons P
LEFT JOIN Address A ON A.PersonId = P.PersonId    ) A
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: If this gives desired output can you mark it as solution?